# How can I make a swipeable composable only consume clicks and drags directly on content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, draggable, swipe, clickable

## Background

- I have built a custom bottom sheet with three anchors.
- There is a FAB for transitioning from `BottomSheetState.Gone` to
  `BottomSheetState.Half`.
- This bottom sheet's content either doesn't
  cover, half covers, or fully covers a full screen `GoogleMap`
  `Composable`.
- The `maxHeight` parameter is the full height in pixels of the parent `Composable`.

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun AnchoredBottomSheet(
    state: BottomSheetState,
    maxHeight: Float,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(initialValue = state)

    val anchors = mapOf(
        BottomSheetState.Gone.toAnchor(maxHeight),
        BottomSheetState.Half.toAnchor(maxHeight/2),
        BottomSheetState.Full.toAnchor(0),
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(maxHeight.toDp())
            .swipeable(
                enabled = swipeableState.currentValue != BottomSheetState.Gone,
                state = swipeableState,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                anchors = anchors,
            )
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    0,
                    swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt()
                )
            }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

## Problem

- When the app is in the `BottomSheetState.Half` state or the `BottomSheetState.Gone`,
- and the user clicks on the `GoogleMap` portion of the screen,
- clicks are caught by the `AnchoredBottomSheet` and do not pass through to the visible (`GoogleMap`) `Composable`.
- For example in this photo the cyan portion of the screen represents the `GoogleMap` portion of the view in the `BottomSheetState.Half` state and it does not receive clicks. [image: BottomSheetState.Half]

## Question

How can I make the my bottom sheet implementation only consume clicks/drags that occur on the content of the bottom sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was in the ordering of the `Modifier` extension invocations. `Modifier.swipeable()` should happen after `Modifier.offset()`.

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun AnchoredBottomSheet(
    state: BottomSheetState,
    maxHeight: Float,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(initialValue = state)

    val anchors = mapOf(
        BottomSheetState.Gone.toAnchor(maxHeight),
        BottomSheetState.Half.toAnchor(maxHeight/2),
        BottomSheetState.Full.toAnchor(0),
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    x = 0,
                    y = swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt(),
                )
            }
            .swipeable(
                enabled = swipeableState.currentValue != BottomSheetState.Gone,
                state = swipeableState,
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                anchors = BottomSheetState.getAnchors(maxHeight),
            )
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```